# Carrying out edge detection on the ROI of image in Matlab

Tags: matlab

How can do edge detection on the ROI (only) of an image without processing the rest of the image? I have tried the following but it is not working:

```
h4 = @(x) edge(x,'log');
Edge_map = roifilt2(Foregound_Newframe,roi_mask,h4);
```

roi_mask is the binary mask that I am using and Foregound_Newframe is the gray image to be processed. Kindly provide an example. Thanks.

Comment: so did you try my suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

The error I see is that the function you are using to do the filtering requires input argument of type `double`, otherwise your calling syntax should work fine.

i.e. use

```
YourFilter = @(x) edge(double(x),'log');
```

When I apply this to an example from`roifilt2` [docs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/roifilt2.html) it works fine (ok it looks weird in this case...):

```
clc
clear

FullImage = imread('eight.tif');
roi_col = [222 272 300 270 221 194];
roi_row = [21 21 75 121 121 75];

ROI = roipoly(FullImage,roi_col,roi_row);

YourFilter = @(x) edge(double(x),'log');

J = roifilt2(FullImage,ROI,YourFilter);
figure, imshow(FullImage), figure, imshow(J)
```

with following output:

[image]